# Kerion vpn control installation error

Tags: vpn

Help me please. I tried to install kerio vpn client. Installation failed with error:

```
kerio-control-vpnclient (9.2.7.2921-1) …
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Failed to start kerio-kvc.service: Unit kerio-kvc.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status kerio-kvc.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript kerio-kvc, action "start" failed.
● kerio-kvc.service - Kerio Control VPN Client
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)
   Active: inactive (dead)

сен 28

ervice:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
сен 28 20:22:41 kokunovai-Inspiron-5748 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
сен 28 20:22:41 kokunovai-Inspiron-5748 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service:13: Executable path is not absolute: pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета kerio-control-vpnclient (--install):
 installed kerio-co 20:22:41 kokunovai-Inspiron-5748 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.sntrol-vpnclient package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

.

What can I do to install this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

your problem was solved?
you may fix it.

edit file */lib/systemd/system/kerio-kvc.service*

find this:

```
ExecReload=pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
```

and replace for:

```
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pkill -SIGHUP kvpncsvc
```